# Filling selection boxes from INI file

Tags: php

The code:

```
$INIFile = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
echo '<center><form method="POST" action=""><br /><table class="specialtable">';
echo '<tr><td><font face="Verdana" color="white">Status:&nbsp;</font></td><td><select name="Status">
<option value="0">Offline</option>
<option value="1">Online</option>
</select></td></tr>';
```

The .ini file:

```
Status = 1
```

This is the code I have. How can I make it so the first option will be read from the the .ini file?

Thanks in advance.

This is an example of what needs to be done, except that it does not work. Serves as an example:

```
echo '<center><form method="POST" action=""><br /><table class="specialtable">';
echo '<tr><td><font face="Verdana" color="white">Status:&nbsp;</font></td><td><select name="Status">
switch('.$INIFile["Status"].')
{
case 0: <option value="0">Off</option>; break;
case 1: <option value="1">On</option>; break;
}
<option value="0">Offline</option>
<option value="1">Online</option>
</select></td></tr>';
```

Comment: have you done a `print_r` on the `$INIfile` variable to see what it gives you? it's an associative array with key => value pairs. You can work with it just like any array.

Comment: It is reading correctly from the file, I just need to add another option, this one being either "Offline" for "0" or "Online" for "1". "Switch" and "case" did not work.

Comment: So is your trouble with writing to the file?

Comment: Negative, it reads correctly, I just need to add option based on the reading of the file. For example, if the "Status = 0", the first option of the selection must be "0, Offline".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$INIFile = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
echo '<center><form method="POST" action=""><br /><table class="specialtable">';
echo '<tr><td><font face="Verdana" color="white">'.$INIFile["Status"].':&nbsp;</font></td><td><select name="Status">
<option value="0">Offline</option>
<option value="1">Online</option>
</select></td></tr>';
```

**EDIT**

```
$INIFile = parse_ini_file('config.ini');
echo '<center><form method="POST" action=""><br /><table class="specialtable">';
echo '<tr><td><font face="Verdana" color="white">Status:&nbsp;</font></td><td><select name="Status">';
switch($INIFile["Status"])
{
case 0: echo '<option value="0">Off</option>'; break;
case 1: echo '<option value="1">On</option>'; break;
}
echo '<option value="0">Offline</option>
      <option value="1">Online</option>
      </select></td></tr>';
```

Comment: Re-wrote the main question.

Comment: I think there was some mixing up of php and html in your code , plz see if above works..

Answer (score 0):

```
$opts = array();     

echo '<select>';

switch($INIFile['Status']):
    case '0': 
        $opts['value'] = '0';
        $opts['text'] = 'Offline';
        break;
    case '1' :
       $opts['value'] = '1';
       $opts['text'] = 'Online';
       break;
endswitch;

echo '<option value="'.$opts['value'].'">'.$opts['text'].'</option>';
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Had to do some adaptations since I did not post the entire code, end up not working as I'm not as skilled. Thank you very much!